# How to implement speech to text (google api) in google spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-text-to-speech

/* Can you help me with a personal project. I'm trying to write a very simple google spreadsheet project for Parkinson's disease speech therapy. I don't know how to complete the following macro :
*/

```
function myFunction() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(word_using_google_speech_to_text_api);
};
```

/* word_using_google_speech_to_text_api = I don't know where and how to include https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize?hl=en

the macro should do the following:

- move one cell down
- listen to micro
- put the result in the cell
  */